# Semantic-ui search local static variable, why no results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

Cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the semantic-ui search component to work correctly...

Many, many examples (semantic-ui.com, jsfiddle, etc) make it look simple.  Following this simple pattern does not produce the same results as with said examples.

I've tried inserting `debugger` statements and using the console to check that the variables exist when needed, tried linking the search component js and css files alongside the rest of the semantic js and css, also tried setting the source, and so on, on the `search` method manually – no luck all around.

Here's my search input:

```
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui icon input" style="width: 100%;">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the js on same page below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        // Setup search
        var content = [
            { title: 'Andorra' },
            { title: 'United Arab Emirates' },
            { title: 'Afghanistan' },
            { title: 'Antigua' },
            { title: 'Anguilla' },
            { title: 'Albania' },
            { title: 'Armenia' }
        ];
        $('.ui.search')
            .search({
                type: 'standard',
                source: content,
                searchFields : ['title'],
            });
    }
</script>
```

Please help. Thank you.

#### UPDATE 1:

I get some kind of resemblance of functionality when I change the jQuery selector to the `.ui.input` like so

```
$('.ui.input')
    .search({
        type: 'standard',
        source: content,
        searchFields : ['title'],
    });
```

But it looks like this...

[image]

#### UPDATE 2:

If I keep the jQuery selector `$('.ui.search')`, the DOM *is* updated with the search results, but still is not presented correctly...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a css conflict. I had added the following at some point to handle displaying some tabular data with many fields. Simply removing it fixed everything.

```
*, body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**TAKE AWAY**: semantic-ui likes to be the only css in town!

Answer (score 1):

Following code working fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/search.css">
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        // Setup search
        var content = [
            { title: 'Andorra' },
            { title: 'United Arab Emirates' },
            { title: 'Afghanistan' },
            { title: 'Antigua' },
            { title: 'Anguilla' },
            { title: 'Albania' },
            { title: 'Armenia' }
        ];
        $('.ui.search')
            .search({
                type: 'standard',
                source: content,
                searchFields : ['title'],
            });
    }
</script>
</head>
<head>
    <title>  Test  </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui icon input" style="width: 100%;">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/search.css">` and `<script src="js/search.js"></script> ` files are the from `semantic/dist/components/`?